# Having a hard time with rolling standard deviations

Tags: sas

I am using SAS UE which doesn´t come with PROC EXPAND. I need to compute rolling std. deviations for return_stock using by using 12 month-window. The date frequency of my dataset is monthly. It looks something like this:

```
      date      permno    ret    return_mkt
     02/01/2000  10000   0.06      0.03
     03/01/2000  10000   0.03      0.08
     ...         
     01/01/2005  10000   0.03      0.04
     02/01/2005  10000   0.06      0.03
     03/01/2005  10000   0.09      0.08
```

my code:

```
data df1;
array ret{0:11} _temporary_;
set df;
by permno;
if first.permno then call missing(of ret{*});
ret{mod(_n_,12)} = monthly_ret;
std_dev = std(of ret{*});
run;
```

Can anyone tell me why I am getting this error? "The variable type of ret is invalid in this context"?

Answer (score 3):

Your temporary array name `ret` is the same as the variable `ret` in the `df` data set.

Change the name of the variable `ret` in the data set to `monthly_ret`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with PROC SQL

```
proc sql;
   create table want as
   select *, 
          (select std(close) from sashelp.stocks 
             where stock=a.stock
               and (intnx('month', a.Date, -11, 'b') le Date le a.Date)) 
                 as std
   from sashelp.stocks as a;
quit;
```